# how disable click button?

Tags: java, android

I have button for download file from server in specific folder and I want

disable button click if file download before by specific name

```
 btinstall.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/download/app-debug.apk");
                if (file.exists()) {
                bt_install.setEnabled(false);
                }
```

Comment: Try with button.setClickable(false);

Comment: You must store downloaded file names either in sqlite or app preferences. Then conditionally enable clicking.

Comment: @AndroidRuntimeException work .. but if open activity again the button not disable :(

Comment: what is the problem with your code?

Comment: @Bernat how do this ?

Comment: @diegoveloper work .. but if open activity again the button not disable :(

Comment: Move the code wich disable the button to onResume() method

Comment: That's 'cause it is not persistent. It only set disable when `btInstall` is clicked. You have to persist it for example using `SharedPreferences` and then when you load activity, check if the flag is setted to control enable/disable state.

Comment: check my solution below

Comment: @ahmed3 [SQLite](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/index.html) & [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the disable button to out of the click so it executes whenever you create the Activity and not only after an action:

```
  final File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/download/app-debug.apk");
  bt_install.setEnabled(!file.exists());
  btinstall.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //Download file and do the rest
```

If you press the home_button your Activity enter in onPause state, causing the onCreate to not execute, a second good location for checking this again in that case is in the onResume method

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
      super.onResume();
      final File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/download/app-debug.apk");
      bt_install.setEnabled(!file.exists());
}
```

Comment: If you press home button and delete the file manually, when you go back to the app, this code not works.

Comment: If you press the home_button your Activity enter in onPause state, causing the onCreate to not execute, a second good location for checking this again in that case is in the onResume method

Answer (score 0):

Here you have, just save a flag after you disable the button and read that flag when you read the button again

```
 SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(); 
 if (prefs.getBoolean("disabled", false)){
     bt_install.setEnabled(false);
 }

 btinstall.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/download/app-debug.apk");
                if (file.exists()) {
                  bt_install.setEnabled(false);
                    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(); 
                    boolean statusLocked = prefs.edit().putBoolean("disabled", true).commit();
                    }
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Yo dont need to store anything. If the user delete de file from an external file manager you will get a false positive. Move the code to onResume method and check if exists.

```
@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/download/app-debug.apk");
    if (file.exists()) {
        bt_install. setClickable(false);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

After API 11, you can store a `Set` in `SharedPreferences`.

Here is an example:

```
private List<String> getDownloadedFileList() {
  SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFS_FILE, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
  List<String> downloadedFileList = Collections.emptyList();
  try {
    downloadedFileList = (ArrayList<String>) ObjectSerializer.deserialize(prefs.getString(TASKS, ObjectSerializer.serialize(new ArrayList<task>())));
  } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
  return downloadedFileList;
}

private void setDownloadedFileList(List<String> downloadedFileList) {
  SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFS_FILE, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
  Editor editor = prefs.edit();

  try {
    editor.putString(DOWNLOADED_FILES, ObjectSerializer.serialize(downloadedFileList));
  } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
  editor.commit();
}

private void addDownloadedFile(String filename) {
  List<String> downloadedFileList = getDownloadedFileList();

  if(!downloadedFileList .contains(filename)) {
    downloadedFileList.add(filename);
    setDownloadedFileList(downloadedFileList );
  }
}

private boolean checkDownloadedFileExists(String filename) {
  return getDownloadedFileList().contains(filename);
}
```

And then, when setting the properties for your button:

```
btinstall.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View view) {
    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/download/app-debug.apk");
    addDownloadedFile("/download/app-debug.apk");
}
```

Finally, set clickable depending on stored values:

```
@Override
public void onResume(){
  super.onResume();
  if (checkDownloadedFileExists("/download/app-debug.apk")) {
    bt_install.setClickable(false);
  }
}
```